# Unable to load the specified metadata resource still comes

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Yes, I know, this is the n'th question around this issue. I tried a lot of mentioned ~solutions, but none of them worked for me.

**Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5.51641, Entity Framework 6.1.1**

My struggle is to configure a well structured ASP.NET project, separate the different entities. I need more entities and in separate folders because of some overlaps among generated class names.
Therefore I've created a *DAL* folder and the first one, the *Production*. My model is quite simple, during the mode creation I've created the *ProductionEntities* entity connection string as it seems bellow:

[image]

Here is the *ProductionModel.edmx* and its properties:
[image]

I checked the assembly with reflector, all the resources are correct:
[image]

After that I've created a webpage and an EntityDataSource within it. If I select the ProductionEntities for *Named Connection*, I get above mentioned error message.

Have anybody some fresh idea for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show relevant source and full exception message.

Comment: There is no code at this point and no exception.

Comment: Then when does this error occur? When adding an EntityDataSource? Do you use "ProductionEntities" as named data source?

Comment: I have an empty webpage (WbbPage1.aspx) I add the EntityDatasource1 to it - Smart tag -> select 'ProductionEntities' for Named Connection, then I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution!

After creating the entity model, it is **MANDATORY to compile** the project! After compilation the VS is going to recognize the entitydatasource wizard works fine...